# How do I initially load an observable array asynchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, knockout.js

This is my viewmodel:

```
function PitchViewModel() {
var self = this;
self.selectedPitch = ko.observable();
self.pitches = ko.computed(function () {
    return $.getJSON("/api/Pitch", function (data) {
        var obs = ko.mapping.fromJS([])
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, obs) ;
       // seems to work, but somehow observables are changed back into objects after binding
        return obs();
    })}, this).extend({ asyncArray: [{ Id: 1, PitchNumber: 1, Length: 0, Width: 0, HasElectricity: false, Name: "Test" }] });

// behaviours
self.selectPitch = function () {
    console.log("inside selectPitch");
    self.selectedPitch(this);
}
```

}

I'm using an async extender as shown here: [asynchronous computed observables](https://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2012/12/10/asynchronous-computed-observables-in-knockout-js/)
adapted a little bit for observablearrays like so (in line 3):

```
var plainObservable = ko.observableArray(initialValue), currentDeferred;
```

In my view i do this:

```
 var domNode = $('#content')[0];
 var pitchViewModel = new PitchViewModel();
 ko.applyBindings(pitchViewModel, domNode);
```

It seems to work fine. The binding happens asynchronously. Pretty cool so far.  
 
**However!**
  
When (in Chrome) I put a breakpoint on

```
return obs();
```

the `obs()`  function is an observableArray and has objects with observable properties.  
But when I break on

```
console.log("inside selectPitch");
```

and inspect `self.pitches()` it has become a 'normal' array with objects the have 'normal' (not observable) properties.

What am I missing here?

BTW: I have tried using a an observableArray for `self.pitches` instead of the computable. But then the ko.applybindings happens before the initialization of the observable array, leading to binding errors.

Thanks for your help.  
Frans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried to run your code but what I SUSPECT happens is that the extender uses the result of the ajax call returned as a Deferred/Promise. Your processing of the results happens in the callback function and is not used for anything afterwards.

You should not mix Deferreds and callbacks like this. Try the following instead:

```
self.pitches = ko.computed(function () {
    return $.getJSON("/api/Pitch")
        .then(function(data) {
            return ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
        });
}).extend({ asyncArray: [...] });
```